# SignalR core receive messages from specific user

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

SignalR core is very new, so the docs detail how to use about it are very rare.
I've done the tutorial from Microsoft and successfully sent messages to all the clients. Now I want to send for specific user, with

```
public Task SendPrivateMessage(string user, string message, string to)
{
    return Clients.User(to).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

the "to" value is the ConnectionID I got from the

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("New ID Connected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Here is my client:

```
public async void InitSignalRAsync()
{
    ChatMessage mess = new ChatMessage();
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chatHub").Build();
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", async (user, message) =>
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mess.user = user;
            mess.message = message;
            Messages.Add(mess);
        });
    });
}


private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendPrivateMessage", User.Text, Text.Text, To.Text);
}
```

The console logs nothing error so I guess it did send but why can't I receive it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For send to client by client's connectionId you should use of Clients.Client(coonectionId)
,Clients.User() is for send to uniqe user by user's Id.to do send message by user id you can try as follows:
-create a CustomUserIdProvider:

```
 public class CustomUserIdProvider: IUserIdProvider
{
    public virtual string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        //get current user id by httpcontext
    }
}
```

and then in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddSignalRCore();

services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
```

now in your hub you can send message by user id:

```
public void Send(string userId, string message)
{
    Clients.User(userId).send(message);
}
```

for more info go to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Comment: How can I get the current userID ?

Comment: Context.User.Identity.Name